# Return dates in ISO-8601 format - Debezium/Postgres plugin

Tags: debezium

According to https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.10/connectors/postgresql.html#data-types, Dates, Times etc are epoch-relative. Is there a way to override this behavior and return them as ISO 8601 formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not supported. One option would be to implement a single message transformation (SMT) to change the date field representation. Or you could provide a PR for implementing this functionality in Debezium, this request has come up a few times.